# Where should I put synchronous side effects linked to actions in redux?

Tags: javascript, redux

(Note: My question was not clearly written, and I was thinking about some things wrong.  The current version of the question is just an attempt to write something that could make the accepted answer useful to as many people as possible.)

I want to have an action that adds an item to a store and registers it with an external dependency.

I could use the thunk middleware and write

```
export function addItem(item) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(_addItemWithoutRegisteringIt(item));
    externalDependency.register(item);
  };
}
```

But the subscribers would be notified before the item was registered, and they might depend on it being registered.

I could reverse the order and write

```
export function addItem(item) {
  return dispatch => {
    externalDependency.register(item);
    dispatch(_addItemWithoutRegisteringIt(item));
  };
}
```

But I track the item in the external dependency by a unique id that it is natural to only assign in the reducer.

I could register the item in the reducer, but I am given to understand that it is very bad form to do side effects in a reducer and might lead to problems down the line.

So what is the best approach?

(My conclusion is: there are a number of approaches that would work, but probably the best one for my use case is to store a handle into the external dependency in Redux rather than a handle into Redux in the external dependency.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use [Redux Thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) middleware, you can encapsulate it in an action creator:

```
function addItem(id) {
  return { type: 'ADD_ITEM', id };
}

function showNotification(text) {
  return { type: 'SHOW_NOTIFICATION', text };
}

export function addItemWithNotification(id) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(addItem(id));
    doSomeSideEffect();
    dispatch(showNotification('Item was added.');
  };
}
```

Elaborating, based on the comments to this answer:

> Then maybe this is the wrong pattern for my case. I don't want subscribers invoked between `dispatch(addItem(id))` and `doSomeSideEffect()`.

In 95% cases you shouldn't worry about whether the subscribers were invoked. Bindings like React Redux won't re-render if the data hasn't changed.

> Would putting `doSomeSideEffect()` in the reducer be an acceptable approach or does it have hidden pitfalls?

**No, putting side effects into the reducer is never acceptable.** This goes against the central premise of Redux and breaks pretty much any tool in its ecosystem: [Redux DevTools](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools), [Redux Undo](https://github.com/omnidan/redux-undo), any record/replay solution, tests, etc. **Never do this.**

If you really need to perform a side effect together with an action, and you also *really* care about subscribers only being notified once, just dispatch one action and use [Redux Thunk] to “attach” a side effect to it:

```
function addItem(id, item) {
  return { type: 'ADD_ITEM', id, item };
}

export function addItemWithSomeSideEffect(id) {
  return dispatch => {
    let item = doSomeSideEffect(); // note: you can use return value
    dispatch(addItem(id, item));
  };
}
```

In this case you'd need to handle `ADD_ITEM` from different reducers. There is no need to dispatch two actions without notifying the subscribers twice.

> Here is the one point I still definitely don't understand. Dan suggested that the thunk middleware couldn't defer subscriber notification because that would break a common use case with async requests. I still don't understand this this.

Consider this:

```
export function doSomethinAsync() {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: 'A' });
    dispatch({ type: 'B' });
    setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch({ type: 'C' });
      dispatch({ type: 'D' });
    }, 1000);
  };
}
```

When would you want the subscriptions to be notified? Definitely, if we notify the subscribers only when the thunk exits, we won't notify them at all for `C` and `D`.

Either way, this is impossible with the current middleware architecture. Middleware isn't meant to prevent subscribers from firing.

However what you described can be accomplished with a store enhancer like [redux-batched-subscribe](https://github.com/tappleby/redux-batched-subscribe). It is unrelated to Redux Thunk, but it causes any group of actions dispatched synchronously to be debounced. This way you'd get one notification for `A` and `B`, and another one notification for `C` and `D`. That said writing code *relying* on this behavior would be fragile in my opinion.

Comment: So the thunk middleware will defer subscriber notification until `addItemWithNotification` returns?  Also, I think I might need to store the return value of `doSomeSideEffect` in redux.  Is the recommended practice to just use another action in the thunk to do that?

Comment: It will invoke the subscribers every time you `dispatch` because thunk may include asynchronous `dispatch`es.

Comment: Then maybe this is the wrong pattern for my case.  I don't want subscribers invoked between `dispatch(addItem(id))` and `doSomeSideEffect()`.  Would putting `doSomeSideEffect()` in the reducer be an acceptable approach or does it have hidden pitfalls?  Also, if notification were deferred until the return from `addItemWithNotification`, how would this be bad in the async case?  In an example like the one in the docs, you would still invoke the subscribers after both the network request and the network response (when the promise resolves), right?

Comment: Whatever you do, **don't put side effects into reducer** :-)

Comment: @gmr I made some edits. I don't understand your last two questions. I also don't understand your use case so it's hard for me to help you—the questions are too abstract so I have to keep my answers abstract too.

Comment: @gmr I also added an example of using return value.

Comment: Thanks so much! Sorry for the unclarity.  I rewrote the question if you have more to add, but I am mostly sorted out now.

Comment: @gmr: I added one more section to the answer.

Comment: Thanks!  What I was briefly thinking the behavior was is something you could implement by having the middleware pass a special dispatching function that checks a flag on itself to determine whether to notify.  The middleware would set this flag to "don't notify," invoke the thunk with the special dispatch function, manually do a notification, and then set the flag to "notify" so that async uses of the dispatch function would notify normally.  But I think the actual behavior is best because it is less likely to surprise people.

Comment: I rewrote the question again to make it less of a wall of text and hopefully more useful to people coming on the question from Google.

Comment: @DanAbramov, In case you add a side effect function in an async thunk action, how will you test it

Answer (score 1):

I'm still in the process of learning Redux; however my gut instinct says that this is could be a potential candiate for some [custom middleware](https://rackt.github.io/redux/docs/advanced/Middleware.html)?

Comment: I just found [this thread](https://github.com/rackt/redux/issues/606) on the redux GitHub, where at the bottom tcoopman says he is doing a side effect in a reducer in a case like mine.  He also mentions a way of doing it in middleware -- is it what you had in mind?  The middleware option is less flexible because you can't put the side effect in the middle of regular reducer logic (for instance, to do some calculations, invoke the side effect based on them, and then put the return value in the new state).  But it is more explicit in some ways.  Curious if there is an official recommendation.

Comment: Haha, as mentioned I'm just starting out so my humble opinion is far from reccomended.  On that note, however, if it works, and you can test it, then ship it ;)